# swift Pod install error

Tags: ios, swift, watch

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
```

- `SwiftyJSON (from`https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)` required by `Podfile`
- `SwiftyJSON (from`https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)` required by `Podfile`
- `SwiftyJSON (from`https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)` required by `Podfile`
- `SwiftyJSON (from`https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)` required by `Podfile`
- `SwiftyJSON (from`https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)` required by `Podfile`
- `SwiftyJSON (= 2.3.2)` required by `Podfile.lock`

  None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies:         `SwiftyJSON (from`https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`),   SwiftyJSON (= 2.3.2)`.

  You have either:

  - out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
  - mistyped the name or version.
  - not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

  Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod  install` by default.

pod update:

```
TEMPLATE END

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=File+exists+%40+dir_s_mkdir+-+%2FUsers%2Fusers%2FMyApp-ios%2FPods%2FTarget+Support+Files%2FAlamofire-iOS8.0&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

```
Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
```

podfile:

```
Podfile:

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyApp Watch app Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

end
```

Comment: What cause this error ? Are you installing it first time ?

Comment: @Abdul Rehman Warraich Yes

Comment: which version of 'SwiftyJSON' you want to use? And your Xcode version?

Comment: Xcode version - 8. SwiftyJSOn 3.1.0

Comment: @РоманДервишов just remove the podfile.lock file from the directory and  run pod install

Comment: Replace the "pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git' " with This   "pod 'SwiftyJSON', ‘~>3.1.0’ "

Comment: And if the result is " Unable to satisfy the following requirements: " then run " pod repo update " and after that install pods

Comment: If problem did solved the let me know. I test it on my side it worked.

Comment: @ Abdul Rehman Warraich Again error TEMPLATE END [!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Comment: @РоманДервишов Kindly show me the terminal screen short. And pod file text.

Comment: @Abdul Rehman Warraich I have mentioned in the title (pod update)

Comment: did you replace " pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git' " with  "     pod 'SwiftyJSON', ‘~>3.1.0’ " ??

Comment: @Abdul Rehman Warraich yes

Comment: target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.1.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyJSON', ‘~>3.1.0’
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', ‘~>3.1.0’
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyApp Watch app Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', ‘~>3.1.0’
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

end

Comment: This is my pod file and I test this on my side and it works. Try to create new project and install these pod file to verify that your project didn't creating any error .

Comment: I was so. After migrating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3, I have these complie errors